# How can I differentiate which action has been clicked in a notification?

Tags: android, kotlin, broadcastreceiver, android-notifications, android-pendingintent

I'm making and Android app that sends notifications with actions several times a day, the problem is that at this moment doesn't matter which action the user clicks it always sends the first intent to the broadcast receiver.

My code:

```
fun sendNotification(title: String, content: String, tomaID: Int){
    val takeShotIntent = Intent(context, TreatmentBroadcastReceiver::class.java).apply {
        putExtra("TomaID", tomaID)
        putExtra("AcctionToma", 0)

    }
    val takeShotPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, NOTIFICACION_ID, takeShotIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT)

    val skipShotIntent = Intent(context, TreatmentBroadcastReceiver::class.java).apply {
        putExtra("TomaID", tomaID)
        putExtra("AcctionToma", 1)

    }
    val skipShotPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, NOTIFICACION_ID, skipShotIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT)

    val postPoneShotIntent = Intent(context, TreatmentBroadcastReceiver::class.java).apply {
        putExtra("TomaID", tomaID)
        putExtra("AcctionToma", 2)
    }
    val postPoneShotPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, NOTIFICACION_ID, postPoneShotIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT)


    val notifyBuilder = getNotificationBuilder(title,content)
    notifyBuilder.addAction(R.drawable.ic_capsula, context.getString(R.string.tomar), takeShotPendingIntent)
    notifyBuilder.addAction(R.drawable.ic_capsula,context.getString(R.string.saltar), skipShotPendingIntent)
    notifyBuilder.addAction(R.drawable.ic_capsula,context.getString(R.string.posponer), postPoneShotPendingIntent)
    mNotifyManager = context.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
    mNotifyManager.notify(NOTIFICACION_ID, notifyBuilder.build())
}
```

And the broadcast receiver class:

```
class TreatmentBroadcastReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {

    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        val idToma = intent.getIntExtra("TomaID", -1)
        val acctionToma = intent.getIntExtra("AcctionToma", -1)
        Log.d("EstasReciviendo", idToma.toString() + " " + acctionToma)

    }
}
```

I need to send an ID and a number that represents what the app should do based on the user selection. The ID is sent without problems but as a I mention above the "AccionToma" is always 0 in the onReceive method no matter which action is tapped.

My logcat output:

```
2019-07-21 17:09:10.993 20286-20286/com.kps.spart.moskimedicationreminder D/EstasReciviendo: 1049 0
```

So, 
How can I differentiate which action has been clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use different unique values, instead of `NOTIFICACION_ID`, for your three `PendingIntent.getBroadcast()` calls.

As it stands, your second `PendingIntent.getBroadcast()` call replaces the first one, and the third `PendingIntent.getBroadcast()` call replaces the second.